# A simple puzzle with no happy endings

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

***I JUST GOT AN EMAIL FROM MY TEACHER, BUT, I CAN'T FIGURE OUT WHAT HE MEANS.***

`With the start of spring, comes the end of fun where The Bat's home becomes just a name.`

---

`When, in the uppercase of Malaysia, a short way to say a pirate’s treasure is, an A in elementary.`

---

`It starts with the number 6, then the 15th, and ½ of a band on the arm but, it’s for your foot.`

---

***WHAT DOES THIS MEAN?***

Comment: Might it be time to add a hint?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I haven't been on my computer lately. I'll add a hint soon.